# Jquery Datatable row grouping with button in each group

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working in datatables for showing Invoice List in my project. In the invoice list, I have row grouping based on Company names. Now, I have to show a checkbox in each invoice row and at last of each group, I should have a Pay button where user selects invoices and click to pay.

I have two questions:

1. I don't know how to bind the Pay button after each group.
2. I don't know how to bind values which invoice is checked.

Please help me.

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: No one is able to help you out without some code demonstrating what you are about to do.  How should anyone be able to deal with a "question" like "_I don't know how to bind the Pay button after each group_"? Which pay button, which group?

Comment: Please refer this example http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html.I need total salary of each group.